# POSIXlt 12-hour time with-out leading zeros

Tags: r

I am attempting to eliminate the leading zero of a 12-hour time value, but for graphing purposes the result must be a POSIXlt value. Therefore, I can-not use regular expressions because they would leave the result as a character instead of a POSIXlt value.

My time value begins as a character.

```
a <- "02:57"
```

Then I use `strptime` to convert the character to the POSIXlt class. Within `strptime`, I use the conversion specification %l, which according to the `strptime` help, displays "12-hour clock time with single digits preceded by a blank".

```
b <- strptime(x = a, tz = "UTC", format = "%l")
```

The variable b is a POSIXlt value, and consists of "current date" + "02:57:00" + "local time zone". I can live with the date and time zone, but the leading zero of the 12-hour time value remains.

How can I eliminate the leading zero of the 12-hour time value and still retain POSIXlt class?

I appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `lubridate`, an excellent package for working with POSIXlt  time objects.

```
library(lubridate)

a <- "02:57"
b <- hm(a)
```

yields

```
> b
[1] "2H 57M 0S"
```

no pesky `0` and sooo much other time goodness to boot. Good luck.